# What is the difference between these ES2015 expressions:

Tags: javascript, axios

What is the difference between:

```
const Api = () => axios.create({ baseURL: '/api' })
```

and

```
const Api = axios.create({ baseURL: '/api' })
```

?

where:

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

is api library link [here](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: One creates a function, the other does not?

Comment: The first is a function. The second will be whatever the `create()` function returns.